# Don't truncate package names in emacs package list.

Tags: emacs, package-managers

When running `list-packages`, long package names get truncated when displayed in the resulting buffer

Is there a way to avoid this truncation, and display the full name no matter how long it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(add-hook 'package-menu-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (setq tabulated-list-format
                  [("Package" 28 package-menu--name-predicate)
                   ("Version" 18 nil)
                   ("Status"  10 package-menu--status-predicate)
                   ("Description" 0 nil)])
            (tabulated-list-init-header)))
```